# Can iText 5 convert PDF to HTML?

Tags: html, pdf, itext

I used `iText 5` to create a nice looking report which includes some tables and graphs. I wonder if iText lets you convert PDF to HTML and if so .. how can one do it?

I believe previous versions of `iText` allowed it, but in `iText 5` i was not able to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  iText has never converted PDF to HTML, only the reverse.

Comment: Do you know of any library that does?

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  I'm a bit wary of any program that claims it can... simply because I know how hard it is.  Not "impossible" mind you, just Very Hard.  It might work for certain classes of PDFs, but I suspect there will always be cases that can trick them.

Comment: While iText doesn't do that, you could use any of several PDF renderers to turn those pages into images, and then embed the images in an HTML page.  Kinda clunky though: no text selection, no fields, lots of bandwidth.

Comment: Just an FYI if anyone stumbles across this now, Aspose PDF will convert a PDF to HTML. I have used this successfully in production on more than one project.

Comment: @mike100111 Will ASPOSE PDF support calligraphy? Because i need conversion in other languages other than English

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at http://www.jpedal.org/pdf_to_html_conversion.php - there is currently a free beta.

Answer (score 0):

Possible to do with Apache Tika (it uses Apache PDFBox under the hood):

```
public String pdfToHtml(InputStream content) {
    PDDocument pddDocument = PDDocument.load(content);
    PDFText2HTML stripper = new PDFText2HTML("UTF-8");
    return stripper.getText(pddDocument);
}
```