# Does java PDFBox library provides method to convert PDF to HTML with images?

Tags: java, html, pdf, pdfbox

I made a research,
and the only tool I found is ExtractText method in CommandLine executable pdfbox-app-2.x.x.jar file with '-html' parameter:
https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html#extracttext
But it does not work for me, because it looses all images, generated HTML file contains only text. So it wouldn't work for me, and I also need jar file, that I can run in my Java Application, not just a CommandLine.

Here is screenshot of my original PDF:
[image]

and here is generated HTML using ExtractText method with '-html' parameter:
[image]

Looks like PDFBox can't do it, rihgt?

Is there any other library, that can convert PDF to HTML, so that it will look exactly like original with all styling and images, tables, checkboxes, etc..?

Comment: Can you update your question to specify whether it needs to be a Java library? I know of a few Python modules that do this I believe. Thanks

Comment: No PDFBox can't do it, see me comments here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3926

Comment: jamescampbell, in the title of this post I mention Java

Comment: Tilman Hausherr, thanks for refered URL!

Comment: Can iText convert PDF to HTML?

Comment: I have no idea. There's an answer from 2011 that says no: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585630/can-itext-5-convert-pdf-to-html